# Azure Python SDK: Create budgets?

Tags: azure

I am trying to create budgets on my Azure subscription. First of all. I tried to use [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/consumption/budget?view=azure-cli-latest) to create budgets.

```
az consumption budget create --amount
                             --budget-name
                             --category {cost, usage}
                             --end-date
                             --start-date
                             --time-grain {annually, monthly, quarterly}
```

I got the following error as a response: `Cost Management supports only Enterprise Agreement, Web direct and Microsoft Customer Agreement offer types`. I was not able to figure out what was the issue but I guess it is because our organization is using Azure Sponsorship.

Then, I saw that Azure offers a [budget REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/budgets/createorupdate) with a PUT request that looks like this:

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/budgets/TestBudget?api-version=2019-10-01
```

I am wondering if it's possible to create a budget using the [Azure Python SDK](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/mgmt/python.html)? There is a documentation for the [Python SDK billing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/billing?view=azure-python) but no examples.

Comment: Please check your subscription plan. If the plan doesn't support Cost Management then you won't be able to create budget using either SDK or REST API.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use Pulumi - it's free for a single user:
https://www.pulumi.com/docs/reference/pkg/azure-native/consumption/budget/

Other option is to use the Azure Arm templates:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/costs/quick-create-budget-template?tabs=CLI

Comment: Thanks Zeeshan Abbas, I will try it and let you know